# Join two tuples

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x

I have matrix A. If printing A, it shows:

```
[(array([0.        , 0.        , 0.00284876]),), 
(array([7.00000000e-09, 2.50000004e-01, 2.84875500e-03]),), 
(array([1.30000000e-08, 5.00000008e-01, 2.84875500e-03]),), 
(array([8.00000000e-09, 7.50000013e-01, 2.84875500e-03]),), 
(array([0.25      , 0.        , 0.00284876]),), 
(array([0.25000001, 0.25      , 0.00284876]),)]
```

I'd like to insert an element a0 to each element of A.
Here is my code:

```
a0 = (np.array([0.33333332, 0.66666662, 0.11111111]))
for i in range(0, len(a)):
    a[i].join(a0)
```

But it shows an error: "AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'join'."
Can you tell me how to debug?
Expect output:

```
[(array([0.        , 0.        , 0.00284876]), array([0.33333332, 0.66666662, 0.11111111])), 
(array([7.00000000e-09, 2.50000004e-01, 2.84875500e-03]), array([0.33333332, 0.66666662, 0.11111111])), 
(array([1.30000000e-08, 5.00000008e-01, 2.84875500e-03]), array([0.33333332, 0.66666662, 0.11111111])), 
(array([8.00000000e-09, 7.50000013e-01, 2.84875500e-03]),array([0.33333332, 0.66666662, 0.11111111])), 
(array([0.25      , 0.        , 0.00284876]), array([0.33333332, 0.66666662, 0.11111111])), 
(array([0.25000001, 0.25      , 0.00284876]), array([0.33333332, 0.66666662, 0.11111111]))]
```

Comment: Why use `.join()` instead of concatenation `+=`?

Comment: because it prints out sum of each element with a0.

Comment: You have an array of tuples where each tuple has an array as the first element. Do you want to extend those arrays or add another element to the tuples?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an array of one-element tuples (intentionally or not). The first and the only element of each tuple is a numpy array. Extend that array:

```
for i in range(len(a)):
    a[i][0].join(a[0])
```

If, however, you want to add the second element to the tuples,  you have to convert `a0` to a tuple:

```
a0 = (a0,)
for i in range(len(a)):
    a[i] = a[i] + a0
```

Answer (score 1):

In your current code, `a0` is not a tuple but a numpy array, you need to add a comma to indicate you want it to be a tuple when you have only one item i.e.:

```
a0 = (np.array([0.33333332, 0.66666662, 0.11111111]),)
```

or explicitly use `tuple()`:

```
a0 = tuple(np.array([0.33333332, 0.66666662, 0.11111111]))
```

After that you can concatenate using `+=`:

```
for i in range(0, len(a)):
    a[i] += a0
```

Try it **[here](https://repl.it/repls/GrizzledDramaticEvaluations#main.py)**.